# Flutter/Firebase - If/Else statement only returns center widget for split second

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to load data from firebase. To handle the event of no data being returned, I have implemented an if/else statement. When I expect no data to be returned the text widget(nested inside a center widget) shows for a split second (<1second) and then disappears. Any ideas why this could be happening? Here is my code:

```
    class ProductListPage extends StatelessWidget {
  String event;

  ProductListPage({this.event});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.deepPurpleAccent,
        title: Text(
          " Cards",
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
        ),
      ),
      body: StreamBuilder(
        stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection('products')
            .where('event', isEqualTo: event)
            .snapshots(),
        builder: buildProductList,
      ),
    );
  }
}

Widget buildProductList(
    BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
  if (snapshot.hasData) {
    return GridView.builder(
        gridDelegate:
        SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(crossAxisCount: 2),
        shrinkWrap: true,
        itemCount: snapshot.data.docs.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return Container(
            height: 25.0,
            width: 25.0,
            child:  Image(image: FirebaseImage(snapshot.data.docs[index]['imgUrl'], maxSizeBytes: 15 * 1024 * 1024)));
        });
  } else {
    // Still loading
    return Center(
      child: Text('Something went wrong'),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes because `snapshot.hasData` return `true` only if only there is data, but `false` while **loading** or **error**, So you see the text because the data is being loaded, it is better to move and return `Text('Something went wrong')` under `snapshot.hasError` , else return a `loader`

```
Widget buildProductList(
    BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
  if (snapshot.hasData) {
    return GridView.builder(
        gridDelegate:
        SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(crossAxisCount: 2),
        shrinkWrap: true,
        itemCount: snapshot.data.docs.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return Container(
            height: 25.0,
            width: 25.0,
            child:  Image(image: FirebaseImage(snapshot.data.docs[index]['imgUrl'], maxSizeBytes: 15 * 1024 * 1024)));
        });
  } else if(snapshot.hasError) {
    // Something is wrong
    return Center(
      child: Text('Something went wrong'),
    );
  }else{
    // Still loading
    return Center(
       child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this ikerfah, I still have the same problem with the Center widget disappearing. I have tried if(snapshot.data == null) as the condition, because I think there isn't an error, just no data being returned, and that hasn't solved the problem. Any other thoughts?

Comment: Can you please update the code you are using now  ?

Comment: Thanks for your help, I managed to find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to resolve the issue by rewriting my code as follows:

```
class ProductListPage extends StatelessWidget {
  String event;

  ProductListPage({this.event});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.deepPurpleAccent,
        title: Text(
          " Cards",
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
        ),
      ),
      body: StreamBuilder(
        stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection('products')
            .where('event', isEqualTo: event)
            .snapshots(),
        builder: buildProductList,
      ),
    );
  }
}
Widget buildProductList(
    BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
  if (snapshot.hasData) {
    if(snapshot.data.docs.length == 0) {
      return Center(
        child: Text('Something went wrong'),
      );
    } else{
    return GridView.builder(
        gridDelegate:
        SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(crossAxisCount: 2),
        shrinkWrap: true,
        itemCount: snapshot.data.docs.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return Container(
              height: 25.0,
              width: 25.0,
              child:  Image(image: FirebaseImage(snapshot.data.docs[index]['imgUrl'], maxSizeBytes: 15 * 1024 * 1024)));
        });
  }}else{
    // Still loading
    return Center(
      child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
    );
  }
}
```